# Setting legend subgroup to hidden using PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, legend

I am trying to set the legend subgroup to hidden with PyQGIS.

The context :

```py
self._project = QgsProject()
layout = QgsPrintLayout(self._project.instance())
map_= QgsLayoutItemMap(layout)
legend = QgsLayoutItemLegend(layout)
legend.setLinkedMap(map_)
layout.addLayoutItem(legend)
for layer_name, layer in self._project.instance().mapLayers().items():
    layer_tree_layer = legend.model().rootGroup().addLayer(layer)
    layer_tree_layer.setLabelExpression("Concat(@symbol_label, ' [', if(@symbol_count=-1, 'N/A', @symbol_count), ']')")
```

I have tried :

```py
QgsLegendRenderer.setNodeLegendStyle(layer_tree_layer, QgsLegendStyle.Hidden)
```

which works but removes the effect of `setLabelExpression`, I don't know why. It's weird because when I do:

```py
manager = self._project.instance().layoutManager()
manager.addLayout(layout)
```

and then go to the layout in QGIS, if I select the legend it refreshes it and it reactivates the expression set by `setLabelExpression`. Maybe I miss some kind of refresh method here...

I have then tried:

```py
legend.setStyle(QgsLegendStyle.Subgroup, legend.style(QgsLegendStyle.Hidden))
```

and:

```py
style = QgsLegendRenderer.nodeLegendStyle(layer_tree_layer, legend.model())
legend.setStyle(style, legend.style(QgsLegendStyle.Hidden))
```

but it doesn't have any effect.

```py
legend.updateLegend()
```

doesn't help.

Comment: What does happen if after `QgsLegendRenderer.setNodeLegendStyle(layer_tree_layer, QgsLegendStyle.Hidden)`, you execute `layer_tree_layer.labelExpression()`? And doing the same after GUI manipulation? Did you also `legend.refresh()` (PS: after adding the legend to the layout and the layout to the manager)? Did you also `layout.addLayoutItem(legend)` after your first block of code like at https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/blob/master/tests/src/python/test_qgslayoutlegend.py#L94-L102? It also seems you need to `legend.setLinkedMap(map)`.

Comment: Executing `layer_tree_layer.labelExpression()` after `QgsLegendRenderer.setNodeLegendStyle(layer_tree_layer, QgsLegendStyle.Hidden)` doesn't help.
I already had : `layout.addLayoutItem(legend)` and `legend.setLinkedMap(map)`.
I tried adding `legend.refresh()`  and `legend.updateLegend()` but it didn't help.
What do you mean by "doing the same after GUI manipulation" ?